# For loop removes only one row of DataGridView per run

Tags: c#, loops, datagridview

I have a function where user chooses a number and clicks a button, it compares the rows of a specific column and if the number is less than the select, it removes the whole row. But my for loop only checks for 1 row each time it's ran even though it's in for loop.

My code:

```
int result = 0;
if (int.TryParse(txtLessThanFollowersCount.Text.Trim(), out result))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
    {
        int parse;
        if (int.TryParse(txtLessThanFollowersCount.Text.Trim(), out parse))
        {
            if (Int32.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString()) < parse)
            {
                dataGridView1.Invoke(new Action(() => dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i)));
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error in the follower count selection", "Error");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
int result = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(txtLessThanFollowersCount.Text.Trim(), out result))
        {
            for (int i = dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                int parse;
                if (int.TryParse(txtLessThanFollowersCount.Text.Trim(), out parse))
                {
                    if (Int32.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString()) < parse)
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Invoke(new Action(() => dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error in the follower count selection", "Error");
        }
```

What i did was iterated through the rows goin all the way from the last to the first :)  When you Remove one row, the Collection is modified and index alters,
because when you are removing first row (if condition is satisfied), the second row becomes the first row. (cuz the first row is gone ! ) got it ? :P

So iterating from the end solves this issue :)

Hope this helps..

Comment: You should change i++ to i--

Comment: Yeah, fixed it :) @venerrik :)